# Transformar un objeto que recibo por parámetro en un array en java

Tags: java

Tengo que comparar miLista con otra que se recibe por parámetro sin tener en cuenta los nulls, es decir, [a, null, b] seria lo mismo que [a, b], para ello necesitaría transformar el objeto "o" en una lista para quitar todos los nulls igual que en miLista con trim(). Pero no se como conseguir el array de o.

Esto es el Objeto "o" que se recibe después:

```
    List<Character> control = Arrays.asList('a', null, 'b', 'c', null, 'd', null);
    assertTrue(listaCreciente.equals(control));
```

Y estos son los métodos que se usan:

```
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        trim();
            
        return (miLista == o) ? true : false;
    }
    //quita los nulls de miLista, por ejemplo si era [a, null, b, null, null, c] 
    //lo dejaria como [a,b,c]
    private void trim() {
        ArrayList<E> temp;
        temp = new ArrayList<E>();
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if(miLista.get(i) != null)
                temp.add(miLista.get(i));
        }
        miLista = temp;
        N = temp.size();
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pero ese return no compara contenido.. compara si son el mismo objeto... deberias tener una funcion que comparara los contenidos, no?

Comment: Todavía no había llegado a eso, pero tienes razón. Eso lo haría con un bucle simple y comparar miLista[i] con o[i]. Pero como podría conseguir el array de o?

Comment: y ese o de que tipo es? porque object puede ser cualquier cosa.... y no es un bucle tan simple.. y si no estan en el mismo orden?

Comment: La llamada a equals son las dos primeras líneas de código, y ahí control sería el Objeto o. Yo necesito guardar esa lista como o[0]=a, o[1]=null, o[2]=b, y asi sucesivamente hasta terminar, después quitar los null, igual que con trim() y por último comparar miLista[0] con o[0], miLista[1] con o[1] así hasta terminar. Tienen que estar en el mismo orden, [a, null, b, null, null, c] sería lo mismo que [a, b, null,  c] pero diferente [a, null, c, null, null, b]

Comment: @Marcos conviertes el `Objeto` que pasas por parametro en un `Map` y luego iteras y sus valores lo pasas a un `Array` entonces podrás comparar ambas listas.

Comment: Hace literalmente 10 minutos que acabo de empezar a ver los Map, como podría hacer eso?